# imakeidx in greek

Tags: imakeidx, makeindex

The issue: Using imakeidx for  indexing in greek language the result is not in the right alphabetical order. I tried to use xindy-package also, but with no success.
The right alphabetical order in greek is

ΑΒΓΔΕΖΗΘΙΚΛΜΝΞΟΠΡΣΤΥΦΧΨΩ

but as you may see In the minimal example below, the index is not in the  right alphabetical order (after compiling).
Any help will be greatfully appreciated!

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[english, greek]{babel}
\usepackage[iso-8859-7]{inputenc}
\usepackage{gfsbodoni}
 \usepackage{imakeidx}

 \makeindex[program=makeindex,columns=2,title=Ευρετήριο όρων,   
  intoc=true,options={-s index_style.ist}]

 \usepackage{hyperref}

  \begin{document}
   Α\index{α}
   Β\index{β}
   Γ\index{γ}
   Δ\index{δ}
   Ε\index{ε}
   Ζ\index{ζ}
   Η\index{η}
   Θ\index{θ}
   Ι\index{ι}
   Κ\index{κ}
   Λ\index{λ}
   Μ\index{μ}
   Ν\index{ν}
   Ξ\index{ξ}
   Ο\index{ο}
   Π\index{π}
   Ρ\index{ρ}
   Σ\index{σ}
   Τ\index{τ}
   Υ\index{υ}
   Φ\index{φ}
   Χ\index{χ}
   Ψ\index{ψ}
   Ω\index{ω}

   \printindex

   \end{document}
```

...and the index_style.ist

```
headings_flag 1
heading_prefix "{\\large\\sffamily\\bfseries "
heading_suffix "}\\nopagebreak\n"
delim_0 " \\dotfill "
delim_1 " \\dotfill "
delim_2 " \\dotfill "
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MakeIndex does not cope with letters beyond ASCII.

Run with `-shell-escape`. I'm not sure Xindy supports iso-8859-7.

```latex
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[english, greek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{gfsbodoni}
\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}

\makeindex[columns=4,title=Ευρετήριο όρων,intoc=true,options=-L greek -C utf8]

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\imakeidxindex\index
  \renewcommand{\index}[2][]{%
    \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
      \imakeidxindex{\detokenize{#2}}%
    \else
      \imakeidxindex[#1]{\detokenize{#2}}%
    \fi
  }%
}

\begin{document}

Α\index{α}
Β\index{β}
Γ\index{γ}
Δ\index{δ}
Ε\index{ε}
Ζ\index{ζ}
Η\index{η}
Θ\index{θ}
Ι\index{ι}
Κ\index{κ}
Λ\index{λ}
Μ\index{μ}
Ν\index{ν}
Ξ\index{ξ}
Ο\index{ο}
Π\index{π}
Ρ\index{ρ}
Σ\index{σ}
Τ\index{τ}
Υ\index{υ}
Φ\index{φ}
Χ\index{χ}
Ψ\index{ψ}
Ω\index{ω}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

I used four columns just to make a shorter image.

[image]

Comment: In both utf8 and iso-8859-7 it works, but I get a bit different result, i.e. the capital letters not appearing, but the alphabetical order is correct. I don't know why this happens. Nevertheless, thank you.
P.S. what is -shell-escape?